# Можно ли на сайте задавать вопросы по техническим вопросам банковской сферы?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Я вот хотел узнать некоторые вопросы связанные с безопасностью дебетовых карточек, не очень могу понять подходит ли данный вопрос сайту. И если подходит то какие теги делать. И вообще хотелось бы понять какую сферу охватывает сайт SO. Как я понимаю он сейчас вышел за рамки чисто программистских вопросов и работает уже в режиме любых технических IT вопросов? Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ваш вопрос на Мете (данный) пример вопроса, о котором идет речь. К примеру, вопрос работы с API MasterCard более чем уместен, как и вопросы алгоритмов расчета кредитного рейтинга.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Мой вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/779230/Безопасность-банковских-карточек , ну про API понятно, я бы и не стал спрашивать

Answer (score 9):

У нас происходит расширение тематики, т.к. вряд ли когда-нибудь появятся нишевые подсайты вроде https://superuser.com, но на русском.

По-этому, у нас помимо чисто программерских вопросов задают вопросы, связанные с системным администрированием и других смежных IT областях.

Касательно сабжа же, если вопрос юридический, то не думаю, что уместно. Хотя, к примеру, были вопросы юридические, помню, по настройке Google Play аккаунта. Но это уже на грани тематики было.

Если вопрос теоретический/технический, на который можно дать объективно верный ответ без всякой демагогии, то, думаю, вполне подходит тематике ru SO.

Answer (score 5):

Как мне кажется, упомянутый пример вопроса можно понять двояко и одна интерпретация уместна, другая — под вопросом. Если вы спрашиваете, какая карта более защищенная с бытовой точки зрения, вопрос нельзя отнести к техническим и лежит он в плоскости наличия различных продуктов у банков в вашем регионе. С другой стороны, если немного модифицировать вопрос, его можно будет рассмотреть как технический: как технически реализуется защита банковских карт разного типа (вопрос безопасности).

Пожалуйста, учтите, что наш сайт о программирование и системном администрировании, а не об IT в общем, его тематика четко задана правилами: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic То есть, как мне кажется, следует разделять вопросы использования технических продуктов (например, интернет банкига), которые вне тематики сайта, от их создания, то есть программирования или администрирования (заметьте, настройке технически, со стороны профессионала, а не пользователя), которые являются сутью ресурса.

Comment: Угу. И если бы примеры/образцы вопросов были бы приведены топикстартером - можно было бы более конкретно показать, где проходит граница онтопика.

Comment: Я и спрашивал про безопасность. Но полностью правильно сформулировать вопрос тоже пока не могу, так как знаний в этой сфере не хватает и мысли путаются. Я надеюсь что мною заданный вопрос хоть и не полностью корректен как вопрос поможет разобраться с существующим ситуацией сейчас.

Comment: @AK По текущему ответу к вопросу, я бы закрыл вопрос как нетематический.

Comment: Вопрос на мете или на SO?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин На основном сайте. Как я понимаю, автор ответа понял вопрос именно в той интерпретации, которая выходит за рамки сайта и подходит больше для сайтов вроде http://www.banki.ru/, чем для нашего.